# Vue $http.get carrega pagina mais retorna NULL

Tags: ajax, vue.js

Estou tentando consumir uma API e o $http.get só retorna NULL.  Chamo um PHP que retorna um json

Que bobagem estou fazendo?

```
 new Vue({
el:'#beerApp',

data:{
    cervejarias: null
},
methods:{
    getChamados: function(){
        this.$http.get('listar_cervejarias.php').then(function(response){
            this.cervejarias = response.data;
        }, function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    this.getChamados();
}


});
```

Comment: Qual o código do `listar_cervejarias.php`?

Comment: Olá rafael
[{"Id":"50630","Operador":"","Id_cadastro":"61693"}]